# DataGridView Sort issues

Tags: .net, vb.net, sorting, datagridview

So I have a data grid view that is named dtgQue here is the Properties of my Column.

```
'Setting the Properties for the Due Date
QueDueDate.Name = "DueDate"
QueDueDate.ValueType = GetType(Date)
QueDueDate.HeaderText = "Due Date"
QueDueDate.CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
```

then after I do add a bunch of rows to that column I then do a

```
dtgQue.Sort(dtgQue.Columns(3), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)
```

But is is not sorting it 100% correct for example here is a set of dates in order of how it sorts. 9/8/2014, 9/2/2014/, 9/15/2014, 10/1/2014 as you see for some reason its putting 9/2 after 9/8 which is not right.

Comment: What is the corresponding `DataGridViewColumn.ValueType`?

Comment: As the answer from @Neverhopeless indicates, you might be using an not ideal datatype in your column, p.e. a string when it is supposed to be a date. Have a look into this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.valuetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you should either use:

```
QueDueDate.ValueType = GetType(string)
QueDueDate.CellTemplate = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell
```

Write custom sorting function where each time `DataGridViewTextBoxCell.Value` will be parsed from `String` datatype to `Date` data type and then use it for comparison.

Or:

```
QueDueDate.ValueType = GetType(Date)
QueDueDate.CellTemplate = New CalendarCell
```

Have a look at [CalendarCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx) here.

If the data is of an appropriate type then it is expected to work/sort correctly.

Hope it helps!